# Using comparison operator in Ocaml produces type error

Tags: ocaml

I'm an OCaml beginner using OCaml 4.12.0 on MacOS. This `let` expression:

```
let gg x y = (x -. y) < 5.0
```

at the toplevel results in:

```
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

Explicitly adding type information, etc., did not fix the problem. In frustration, I visited the online REPL TryOCaml, and the expression was accepted without error, returning the type signature of:

```
val f : float -> float -> bool = <fun>
```

as expected. But I'd like `utop` to work on the Mac - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Base` (or `Core`, or `Core_kernel` and other Janestreet standard libraries) the comparison operator and its friends (like various equality operators) work only on values of type int. For all other values you have to use specialized comparison operators provided by the module that implements that type, e.g., to compare two floats,

```
Float.(3.14 < 4.14)
```

to compare strings,

```
String.("hello" <> "world")
```

And, using your example,

```
let gg x y = Float.(x -. y < 5.0)
```

or even

```
let gg x y = Float.(x - y < 5.0)
```

Notice that we don't need to use the ugly `-.` operators anymore and can use `-` (and other arithmetic operators) as they are all defined specifically for float in module Float.

Besides, the notation `Foo.(<expr>)` is a short-hand for `let open Foo in <expr>` and is called *local open*.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Entering `let gg x y = Float.((x - y) < 5.0)`correctly returned `val gg : Core.Float.t -> Core.Float.t -> bool = <fun>` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very possibly you're using a library that overrides the built-in meaning of `<` in OCaml. Some people (not me) think the polymorphic comparison operators are a problem.

One problem with this (IMHO) is that it causes confusing results like this.

For example, the Jane Street Base library is documented as overriding the polymorphic comparison operators: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/index.html

Comment: Easy enough for @user1492431 to test this by trying `(<);;` in their toplevel and seeing what type it returns.